# the quickest way to read java text files

Tags: java, file, hashtable

I just inhereted some code, and I'm not good wiht java. I'm wondering if the current method this person implemented is the quickest way to read and calculate java text files. Im trying to read them into memory and just do a quick string calculation. I'm thinking this can't be it.

Say I have some text files:

```
1: AAAATTTTCTC
2: AATTTCTCCTC
3. ....
```

Now say I have 10,0000 of those but want to store them in memory for some quick hash-map (or something similar)...

In Java...and only Java...what would the best way to do this?

Comment: *"what would the best way to do this?"* What did your profiler suggest?  Don't include useless noise like as in a sig.  If you care who you are, [edit you profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1265749/jwillis0720), (we don't care).

Comment: And this would be part of the reason that programs take up gigabytes of ram these days...

Comment: It may be useful to share what the current method is and exactly why you think it can be done better.

Comment: "10,0000" is an odd way of expressing a number. Did you actually mean ten thousand, or a hundred thousand?

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way, from a coding perspective is this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/your/file"), charset);
```

You can then loop over the lines and do what you need with them.

Answer (score 1):

Use Scanner  to read the txt file

```
try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list=  new ArrayList<String>();
    while(in.hasNext()){

    list.add(in.nextLine());

    }
}catch(IOException ex){
 throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

and you need `java.util` ass import

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to read a text file :

```
public class RegexTester {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("c:/file-path/file-name");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String text = null;

    while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Text from file
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```